# DocuSign iOS app custom URL scheme?

Tags: ios, docusignapi

I'd like to launch the DocuSign iOS app from the iOS application I'm working on. Does the DocuSign app have a custom URL scheme that I can use to open it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no URL scheme, but they do have an iOS library you can integrate. It makes calls to their server. You will also have to create a developer account with them.

DocuSign SDK:
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ios-sdk

DocuSign Developer Center:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center

The SDK is actually better than an URL scheme, since it lets the user sign a document right from inside your app!

Comment: Thanks, Zaid. I do know about their iOS library but unfortunately the project I'm working on is built against iOS 6 and the library seems to be only compatible with iOS 7 and up, so unfortunately that's not an option.